# Add SQL Server Registered Server Using PowerShell After Version Upgrade

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssms

In my original local installation of SQL Server 2012, I was able to use PowerShell to add Registered Servers to SSMS.  When I upgraded to 2014, the Registered Servers did not carry over from the 2012 to the 2014 version.

As I attempt to use PowerShell again to add a Registered Server to my SSMS 2014 client, PowerShell can only reach the 2012 SSMS client, not the 2014 SSMS client.  There are no visible paths or ways to tell PowerShell that I want to add to the 2014 SSMS client.

Here is the code I am running:

```
sqlps
cd .\SQLRegistration
cd '.\Database Engine Server Group'
New-Item SomeNewGroupName
cd SomeNewGroupName
New-Item PROD
cd PROD
New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname SomeServerName) -itemtype registration -Value "server=SomeServerName;integrated security=true"
```

How do I make PowerShell talk to the 2014 SSMS client?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If for some reason the registered servers didn't come over, right click the group in SSMS, choose "export" and then import it to where it needs to go.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that was an option, and it did work!  So, thank you!  But my original question still stands... how do I get PowerShell to make changes directly to the 2014 SSMS client?

Comment: If I were to speculate, I'd guess that you need to be specific about what version of SMO you're using for export and import. But I don't have that specific configuration to test. Any reason not to use a CMS and skip all the headaches?